# How can I return a string value after split in c#

Tags: c#

I am getting an error saying

> Syntax error value expected.

In this code

```
public string[] TabAsDelimiter(string strValue)
{     
      string data = strValue;
      string[] words = data.Split('\t');
      foreach (string word in words)
      {
        return word[];
      }
}
```

returns the values in the array

Comment: what is `word[]` supposed to do? there's no point in the for loop if you're just going to return the first element

Comment: `words` is your string array variable. Just return it with `return words;`. You don't need a `foreach` if you're returning all of them. There's also no use in copying the input string into `data`, for that matter; you can use `strValue` directly.

Comment: `return word[]` => this must be `string[] words = data.Split('\t').ToArray();` and the return statement must be placed outside `foreach` loop, e.g. `return words;`.

Comment: You are not clear, is the return type `strring[]` the desired outcome? Your title suggests a single string.

Comment: Your question would be received a lot better when you indicate what you want exactly, for instance with an example of how you want to use it. Or add a list of input/output pairs.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - It is not necessary to call `ToArray` on the result of the `Split` method.  It already returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

`word[]` is wrong. If you want make `word` an array, you could use `word.ToCharArray()`, but it would result in `char[]`, not `string[]`.

But I really doubt that you want to return char array. Moreover, you would return only character array of the first word! Because method finishes as soon as it reaches `return` statement.

I think you just want to return array of words split by tab. In this case, your method should look like:

```
public string[] TabAsDelimiter(string strValue)
{
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue)) return null;     
  return strValue.Split('\t');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return data.Split('\t');
```

After Split you got an array.

Comment: The whole function content can be replaced with `return strValue.Split('\t');`. Which, honestly, is too simple a statement to justify the existence of a separate function for it. Whatever calls this function should just call `strvar.Split('\t')` directly.